# Does CodeKit support the sweet.js compilation?

Tags: codekit, sweet.js

I am just wondering if CodeKit supports the compilation of Sweet.js files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You could possibly set up your own hook and run a custom shell script when a JavaScript file changes.